How do I get the "webform closed" status message to display when the status is set to "scheduled"?
I have a status message to display when a webform is closed (closed status message); however, it does not display when a form is currently closed but the status is set to "scheduled". It displays only when the status is set to "closed". Since I am required to display this message, I have to leave the status on "closed" and cannot schedule it to re-open. This seems like a bug but is there any way to work around this?

What does Webform show instead of your message? That's missing from this post.

It shows a default message "This form has not yet been opened to submissions."

"Closed status message" isn't a configuration field in Webform. Can you get the precise name of the configuration form field label so we are discussing the same thing? I think it is "Form closed message". Add that information and the information in the comment above to the question. I think this question is going to be 'Why are the "Form open message" and "Form closed message" being overridden by "Default open message" and "Default closed message" when forms are scheduled?'.
